# Resource releasing in method scope vs using block scope in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, scope, using-statement

Which method is more efficient (time, memory, resource-releasing, exception scenario) ?

```
public static string getFileData(string filePath)
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(fs))
        {
            return r.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

OR

```
public static string getFileData(string filePath)
    {
        return (new StreamReader(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)).ReadToEnd());
    }
```

Comment: Well clearly the second one simply *doesn't* release the resources... it's not about efficiency, it's about correctness. I'd just use File.ReadAllText though...

Comment: I would personally use the using statement, to explicitly show that the resource is managed and disposed of when others read the code, it is much clearer what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

first without a doubt - you're atleast disposing of the resources you're using. In your second case, maybe if it was being stored into a static variable so only reading once it might be okay, but still not disposing diligently

Answer (score 0):

CLR will generate one code approximately for both code, so two code are same

Comment: No, it won't. One will dispose the FileStream, the other will not.